# Bound on the distance from points to the boundary of a hyperbolic surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

Fix $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, $\Sigma$ a surface with boundary and let $\mathcal{T}_{\Sigma}(L_{1},...,L_{n})$ denote the Teichmüller space of hyperbolic structures of $\Sigma$ with geodesic boundaries with lengths given by $L_{1},...,L_{n}$. Now let $\mathcal{T}_{\Sigma}^{(\epsilon)}(L_{1},...,L_{n})=\{\sigma\in\mathcal{T}_{\Sigma}(L_{1},...,L_{n}):sys_{\sigma}>\epsilon\}$ where $sys_{\sigma}$ is the length of the shortest curve.

Is there a known bound $c(\epsilon,L_{1},...,L_{n})$ such that for $p\in\Sigma$ and $\sigma\in\mathcal{T}_{\Sigma}^{(\epsilon)}(L_{1},...,L_{n})$

$$d_{\sigma}(p,\partial\Sigma)<c(\epsilon,L_{1},...,L_{n})$$

where $d_{\sigma}(p,\partial\Sigma)$ is the distance from $p\in\Sigma$ to the boundary with respect to $\sigma$ and $c(\epsilon,L_{1},...,L_{n})$ is independent of $\sigma$?

I've seen bounds on the so called injectivity radius (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.05573.pdf) which is somewhat related. However, for example, it doesn't need a bound on the systole which is necessary here from the collar lemma. Basically, I want to know if bounding the systole from below is enough to bound the distance from points in the surface to the boundary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you do **not** mean "independent of the $L_1, \dotsc, L_n?$"

Comment: Yep sorry just fixed!

Comment: There are even explicit bounds on the diameter of the entire surface, provided you allow $c$ to depend on the genus of $\Sigma$. Otherwise, there is no a bound you are looking for.